# Local Chamber of Commerce business directory and Local SEO?

Tags: seo, google-search, local-seo, directory-listing

Here is my question: Is being listed in a local Chamber of Commerce business directory good for local SEO? I was talking my local chamber's membership director and it occurred to me my that it might be a good idea. I know Google looks down on link farms, but given that most chambers are accredited groups, I would think it would be a good thing. Just looking for some possible feedback.

Comment: There are too many factors that apply. It really depends upon the website itself and not the fact that it is a Chamber of Commerce website. One might have authority, while another may not. I am sure it is not a bad thing, it just may or may not help. If it helps, then by how much? Who knows without reviewing the Chamber's site?

Comment: That makes sense. I just wanted to make sure that I wasn't telling them wrong. But safe to say that it can't hurt, correct?

Comment: It can't hurt... much. Just kidding! ;-) It can't hurt. I cannot see any harm. Generally, these sites are relatively safe. It would be more for any link value, however, if they list address and phone numbers and what not, that validates the business owners site and may help with branding. Cheers!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also asked this question on twitter and got this response:

**ME:** Question: Is being listed in a local #ChamberofCommerce business directory good for local #SEO? #LocalSEO

**Frank J. Kenny ‏@FrankKenny:** A link from the chamber's website to your is always a good idea.

**ME:** @FrankKenny That's what I thought, just curious and wanted to make sure Google didn't see it as a link farm.

Therefore with what Frank said on twitter and **@closetnoc** said in the comments above I am going to say yes it is a good thing.

**Frank J. Kenny ‏@FrankKenny:** Not at all Chad. Good, solid, link juice.